# Rename shortcut with Visual Studio Setup Project Creates new folder in "Program Files"

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment, visual-studio-setup-proje, shortcut-file

I used Visual Studio Setup project to create MSI installer for a WPF application. The setup project configured to create a shortcut of application on desktop.

Now I have requirement to rename the shortcut. I renamed the shortcut under setup project "File System" and created the new setup. But when I am installing the setup, it is creating a new folder under "C:\Program Files" with new name of shortcut and installing all the files there. The folder with old name is still there in "C:\Program Files".

Is there a way to just rename the shortcut on desktop? I am fine if the folder name under "C:\Program Files" remains as it is. In short, I don't want a duplicate folder under "C:\Program Files". Thus it is creating a duplicate folder.

I increased the minor version for all .dll files and setup version also.

Also I know Wix is providing more options and it is more flexible, however I have to do this with VS Setup project only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue. By mistake I changed "Product Name" property of Setup Project and due to that it was creating a new folder under "C:\Program Files".

To just rename ShortCut on desktop rename the ShortCut in File System of Setup Project and create setup. When you run this new setup it will rename the shortcut on desktop.